# How to create a django form field with html

Tags: django, django-forms

at the moment the html page looks something like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'sequence_details' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="container pb-3">
        <table class="table">
            {{ form.as_table }}
            <tr><th><input type="text" id="extrafield"></th></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Download">
    </div>
</form>
```

extrafield appears as a text field but any text entered into it does not get sent to the backend, i.e. the result of `form.cleaned_data.get("extrafield")` is always `None`, no matter what was entered. I would like to be able to customise extrafield and write my own html for it, which is why I'm not just adding it to the form object. How can I get the result of extrafield's input to show up in form.cleaned_data?

Answer (score 0):

you can get that by this in your .views function:

```
    extrafield = request.POST.get('extrafield')
```

before that you need to give a name to your input:

```
<tr><th><input type="text" name="extrafield" id="extrafield"></th></tr>
```